# Microsoft Office 2010 - Programs crash at direct opening

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have been having this problem the past few days. I am working on a project I plan on getting working through VBA in Excel 2010, and that has resulted in an Excel file containing numerous Macros.

I don't remember if this was the case form the first time I saved the file, but now, every time I try to open the specific file by double clicking on it, Excel crashes and stops working.
If I try to open Excel seperately, AFTER I try to open the file on double click, so as to open it from there, it ONLY works, if I close the Document recovery option that appears after a previous crashing. That is, the file opens if I open it from an already open Excel program from the very beginning, or, if I make the mistake to double-click on the file, I need to close the Recovery option, before I manage to open it properly.

The said file also has a (!) sign on its icon, possibly something related with the macros it contains.

A solution for this would be greatly appreciated.

IMPORTANT EDIT:
I just noticed this goes on, with every other Microsoft Office 2010 program. I think this should help you determine the problem better.

Comment: The first required step will be to attempt to repair your Office installation.

Comment: @Ramhound Problem remains.

Comment: Have you tried Safe Mode by chance?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that may be happening:

1. You have an Unknown Virus lurking in your computer
2. You have a Missing DLL
3. You do not have the latest update of Windows
4. Your version of System 32 is corrupt

Here are the ways to fix some of these:

1. Get a Virus Protector
2. Take your Computer/Laptop to a local Best Buy Store (They'll be happy to help)
3. Update Windows and your Office Apps